# Clases en Python, problemas al ejecutar

Tags: python, diseño-de-clases

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python y no puedo ejecutar mi primera clase, me estoy guiando mediante cursos online, en el video si ejecuta

```py
class Moto(object):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.color = "vino"
        self.tipo = "Deportivo"
        self.ruedas = 4
        self.m = m

    def movimiento(self):
        if self.m == True:
            print("Acelerar")
        else:
            self.m = False
            print("Frenar")


def main():
    while True:
        print("Acelerar")
        print("Frenar")
        valor = int(input(">"))
        if valor == 1:
            m = Moto(True)
        else:
            m = Moto(False)
if __name__ == "main":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema seguro es que no ves nada por pantalla y esto se debe a que no llamas el método `movimiento`. Además te puedes ahorrar algunas cosas.

Un pequeño detalles es que no es necesario heredar de `object`, por lo que puedes escribir tan solo `class Moto()`. Ahora en el método `movimiento` no es necesario hacer `if self.m == True` es tan sencillo como hacer `if self.m` aquí python evalúa el valor booleano del dato.

Como te dije al principio el error es que no llamas al método `movimiento`. Lo ideal es que antes de iniciar el ciclo crees el objeto ya que no es muy eficiente ir creando un objeto en cada iteración y lo mejor es ir cambiando sus atributos, ya que por algo tienes el método `movimiento`.

He modificado el método `movimiento` para que podamos cambiar el movimiento del vehículo.

```py
...
    def movimiento(self, mover):
        if mover: #si mover es True
            self.m = True
            print("Acelerado")
        else:
            self.m = False
            print("Frenar")

m = Moto(None) #creamos el objeto inicializado como None, o podría ser False
def main():
    while True:
        print("Acelerar \nFrenar")
        valor = int(input(">"))
        if valor == 1:
            m.movimiento(True) #indicamos que se mueva
        else:
            m.movimiento(False) #indicamos que frene
```

De esta forma solo tenemos un único objeto y vamos cambiando su atributo `m` de acuerdo a lo que se introduzca.